# bind_result() - Number of variables doesn't match number of fields

Tags: php, mysqli, binding, prepared-statement, fetch

Code:

```
// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($id === false) {
    //filter failed
    die('id not a number');
}
if ($id === null) {
    //variable was not set
    die('id not set');
}

//white list table 
$safe_tbl_name = '';
switch($tbl_name){
    case 'Table1': 
        $safe_tbl_name = 'MyTable1';
        break;
    case 'Table2':
        $safe_tbl_name = 'MyTable2';
        break;
    default:
        $safe_tbl_name = 'forum_questions';
};

$sql="SELECT * FROM `$safe_tbl_name` WHERE id=?";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)){
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
$stmt->execute();
}
else{
   //error !! don't go further
   var_dump($con);
}
$stmt->bind_result($result);

$rows = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bordercolor="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong><?php echo $rows['topic']; ?></strong></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><?php echo $rows['detail']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>By :</strong> <?php echo $rows['name']; ?> <strong>Email : </strong><?php echo $rows['email'];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#F8F7F1"><strong>Date/time : </strong><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't
>   match number of fields in prepared statement in
>   C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php on line 47

And this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all() in
>   C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php on line 49

Comment: change this line $stmt->bind_param("i", $id); to $stmt->bind_param("s", $id); or convert $id to (int)$id

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Yeah a explanation would be great... First of all, the error happens some line above the sql statement... second, the `$id` is a integer.. why should he used it as string in his statement? That wouldn't be so good I think..? May you van `var_dump($id)` and see whats the value of ID before you check it to false..?

Comment: Got this when adding 'var_dump($id);'  C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php:16:boolean false
id not a number

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_GET)` too?

Comment: @ Daniel Smith because you are not passing number in id in the url it should be integer

Comment: I got this now when adding var_dump(INPUT_GET);    C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php:16:int 1
C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php:17:boolean false

Comment: INPUT_GET is a constant, and not what was asked for. $_GET != INPUT_GET

Comment: oh im sorry, ok so I got this now C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php:16:
array (size=1)
  'id' => string '<? echo $rows['id']; ?>' (length=23)
C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php:17:boolean false

Comment: Sounds like short-tags aren't enabled. Stop using `<?` and replace with `<?php`.

Comment: More specifically on `<? echo $rows['id']; ?>`.

Comment: Ok did that now and got this when I clicked on line 25 C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php:16:
array (size=1)
  'id' => string '25' (length=2)
C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php:17:int 25

Comment: And also an errormessage showed up: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php on line 42

Comment: That's resolved your first issue then, now you need to work out why your `prepare` is failing.

Comment: So I got this now :mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php on line 47

Comment: And this: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all() in C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php on line 49

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using [bind_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) properly.

> Binds columns in the result set to variables.

You are trying to bind the entire result set into a single variable.
You need to provide a variable for each column in the result set.

```
$stmt->bind_result($topic,$detail,$email,$name,$datetime);
```

Here is where it fits in:

```
$sql="SELECT `topic`,`detail`,`email`,`name`,`datetime` FROM `$safe_tbl_name` WHERE id=?";
if($stmt=$con->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($topic,$detail,$email,$name,$datetime);
    //while($stmt->fetch()){  not wrong, but not necessary to loop if only one row
    $stmt->fetch();  
        echo "<table width=\"400\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\">";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"1\" bordercolor=\"1\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">";
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td bgcolor=\"#F8F7F1\"><strong>$topic</strong></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td bgcolor=\"#F8F7F1\">$detail</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td bgcolor=\"#F8F7F1\"><strong>By :</strong>$name<strong>Email : </strong>$email</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td bgcolor=\"#F8F7F1\"><strong>Date/time : </strong>$datetime</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</table>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    //}
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use the `*` in your SELECT, you could try the following non-bind_result method.  (all examples that I have read online only use bind_result when not using `*` in the SELECT.

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
    $rows[]=$result->fetch_assoc();
}else{
    echo "execute failed";  // but I don't think this is your problem
}
// $rows['topic']
// $rows['detail']
// $rows['email']
// $rows['name']
// $rows['datetime']
```

Comment: I got this error atm: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php on line 47

Comment: And this:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all() in C:\wamp64\www\forrrumm\view_topic.php on line 49

Comment: I get 29 when I do that and 28 if I click the topic with id 28

Comment: I tried the code under execute now and it seems to work better now. It echos out the information from my db but I get errors telling me that 'topic' is an unidentified index and so are 'detail, email, name and datetime' as well

Comment: Ok, where in the code should I put this?: $stmt->bind_result($topic,$detail,$email,$name,$datetime);

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I marked your answer as green as well. Have a nice weekend.